# How to configure logging of subversion operations performed by Hudson?

Tags: svn, logging, hudson

We use Hudson as our CI server and SVN as our source control system. We normally tag our builds by means of the "Tag this build" command, which works fine. But today, I wished to create a branch, which is the same from the SVN perspective. However, Hudson refused to do so.

We would really like to see the logs, but we do not know the logger names! The documentation suggests that we look in the source code (dah) or the mailing lists.

Is anyone out there, knows where to find these logger names? Or, specifically, we need the subversion logger names.

Thanks a lot to all the good Samaritans.

Comment: You want to see the code logging output?  To make much sense of it, you'll need to look at the source anyway - why do you reject looking at the source?

Answer (score 1):

Please file an RFE for listing up logger names. I think it's a great feature.

"hudson.scm.SubversionTagAction" logs "Tag this build" command, and "hudson.scm.SubversionSCM" is the general Subversion logging.

Comment: OK, I will. How do I add an RFE?

Comment: I activated these logs, at least I think I did. However, no log messages are seen. I presume, that building a project should generate a few hudson.scm.SubversionSCM log messages, at least saying that no checkouts are necessary, but nothing. How can I make sure the logs are ON?

Comment: I did it exactly as described in the wiki. Still the subversion log is empty. I log All output from hudson.scm.SubversionTagAction and hudson.scm.SubversionSCM. Granted, we do not create tags recently, but subversion is constantly polled for changes and I expect to see checkouts in the log. Nothing.